# Transferring Azure Training Badges from one account to another

Tags: azure

I have Azure training badges / trophies on an account with a business email which I no longer have access to which I want to transfer to my personal account - can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Certification - Transcript - Missing Exams or Certificates: https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/mcp/forum/mcp_prof-mcp_trans-mcp_missingexams
Microsoft Certification - Missing Badge: https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/mcp/forum/mcp_exams-mcp_badges-mcp_missb
Microsoft Certification - Profile/MCID Assistance: https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/mcp/forum/mcp_prof-mcp_mcid

Answer (score 0):

If your azure training badges are in **Credly**, then you can follow the below steps to merge the business account to your personal account.

1. Log into the account you'd like to designate as your default account on *https://www.credly.com/users/sign_in*
2. Navigate to **Settings** from profile icon drop down menu in the upper right corner of the screen
3. Navigate to the **Account** tab in the left-hand menu
4. Click on the link to the right of **Merge Account**
5. Enter the email address and password of the account you want to merge into the default account
6. You will receive an email at the email specified in step 5 with an **authorization code**
7. Enter the authorization code into the text box and confirm the merge All accepted and pending badges from the merged account will be added to the default account
8. The email address from the account that was merged into the default account will be added as a secondary email(s) to the master account.

[Video - How to merge accounts?](https://support.credly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041542572-Video-How-do-I-merge-my-accounts-#:%7E:text=Search-,Video%20%2D%20How%20do%20I%20merge%20my%20accounts%3F,-April%2006%2C%202020)

[Reference Article](https://support.credly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041542572-Video-How-do-I-merge-my-accounts-#:%7E:text=Navigate%20to%20the%20%22Account%22%20tab%20in%20the%20left-hand,you%20want%20to%20merge%20into%20the%20default%20account)

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. The problem is the account I want to merge is a work email that I no longer have access to as I have left the company.

Comment: If you do not have access to an email address you have registered, but you have access to both accounts on Credly that you'd like to merge, you can do so in reverse.  Please watch this [short video](https://support.credly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029631791-Video-How-to-Merge-Accounts-in-Reverse-)